# Mercurial: can I ignore a file for push/pull but still commit? (.hgsub)

Tags: mercurial, push, ignore, subrepos

I have a repo with two sub-repos set up like this:

```
project/
   |-- folder1
   |-- folder2
   |-- www       [subrepo]
   |-- dev       [subrepo]
```

On Machine A, I have checked out project, www, and dev, and modified .hgsub as such.
I have to commit this in order for the www and dev subrepositories to be recognised by hg (commit -S, etc).

However Machine B only uses the www functionality of the project, so it looks like this:

```
project/
   |-- folder1
   |-- folder2
   |-- www       [subrepo]
```

Again, the .hgsub in Machine B only has an entry for www, and I have to commit this for hg to recognise it as a subrepo.

What I'd like to do is do push and pull to my central repo but NOT push/pull the .hgsub.
Otherwise, if I commit and push .hgsub from Machine A say, and then pull from Machine B, I automatically get the dev subrepo as well as the www subrepo that I don't want.

So I modify .hgsub again on Machine B to only have www and commit it for it to take effect.
I do some work in the www subrepo on Machine B and want to push back out to the central repo, but it will also push out the change to .hgsub. Now when I pull on Machine A, my 'dev' subrepo is gone and I have to add it back to .hgsub again, and I go back and forth like this until I pull my hair out in frustration.

Is there any way to get around this? .hgsub must be locally committed on each machine in order for the subrepos to work, but I don't want them to be pushed or pulled.
Is there a .hgignore for push/pull?

cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A push/pull doesn't operate on files, it operates on changesets.

As such, there is no way to push/pull a partial changeset, either you push/pull it, or you don't.

If you don't want the repository to *always* contain that file/sub-repository, you shouldn't organize your projects like that. Instead you might want to look into setting up a secondary project with just the sub-repositories you need for that other site.

In other words, you might look into having 2 projects, one with all the sub-repos, the other with just a few.

Comment: Thanks. I had a sneaking feeling that subrepos weren't quite right for my problem, it's just that it seemed a great way to handle having a core package with `folder1` and `folder2`, and then a number of optional modules. such that I don't have to remember to merge between branches etc. ah well.