# Would like to ignore files with tortoisehg

Tags: tortoisehg

In tortoisehg, in wpuld like ignore hello.php files. I put it in the .hgignore files. But when i make pull with another project, hello.php merged with the hello.php file from another project.

How can i really ignore files with tortoisehg, it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.hgignore` tells Hg (and thus TortoiseHg) which files to ignore when doing a commit. It has nothing to do with what happens when you pull from another project. You will pull whatever is in the remote repository, whether or not it's listed in `.hgignore`.

Comment: Thx.Would you have any idea how can i proceed if I want hello.php file  not merged during pull/push?

Comment: That is not possible, because push and pull work on changesets, not files. See [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7201934/2057919). You can always just keep a copy of your hello.php file, do the pull, and replace the pulled version with your own file.